# Pygame display not being updated even after pygame.display.update() is called

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a simple program in pygame where it will display lines that will lead up to your mouse but the lines won't go away even after I call `pygame.display.update()`. The whole screen starts to get filled with lines. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((720,360))
pygame.display.set_caption("Random Code")

run = True
font = pygame.font.SysFont("javanesetext",30,True,False)#Bold = True, Italic = False
text = font.render("Hi",1,(255,0,0))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(text,(36,36))
    pygame.draw.line(win,(255,255,255),(mousePos[0],0),(mousePos[0],360))


while run:
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    redrawGameWindow()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Could you please help me fix this problem?

Comment: Can you share your error log ?

Comment: @dejdej, there's no error log. That was the problem. White lines would just start filling up the screen. But thanks to Thaer A and The Big Kahuna, I've already fixed the problem. Thanks for your caring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to redraw the background of the screen. `pygame.display.update()` only adds to the screen, it does not clear it and draw. So you need to clear it yourself with `win.fill((0,0,0))`. this draws the whole screen black so you can draw on it again

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    win.blit(text,(36,36))
    pygame.draw.line(win,(255,255,255),(mousePos[0],0),(mousePos[0],360))
```

Comment: What would happen if I used an image as a background? Would I still need to do `win.fill((0,0,0))`?

Comment: @YQStack No, as long as you have something being drawn over the whole screen, its fine. Because once you put something on the screen, you cant take it off, so you have to cover it up with something else, a background, which can be anything, a colour or a image

Answer (score 1):

Add `win.fill((0, 0, 0))` to your `redrawGameWindow()` function to redraw the backgroud on the screen:

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(text,(36,36))
    pygame.draw.line(win,(255,255,255),(mousePos[0],0),(mousePos[0],360))
```